# How to track changes in size of a certain file in Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I want to monitor the time when the size of an SQL database log file, `databaseName.ldf` changes so that I can compare it with the time that SQL queries were executed on in order to determine which SQL queries/behaviour has the biggest effect on the size of my `databaseName.ldf` files.

I've tried third party tools like [Size Matters](http://skwire.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/size-matters.php) and [Folder Changes View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html) but the problem was they only log the latest change. I wanted to see all the changes in file size over time.

I would prefer if it uses non-polling method or triggered by events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) might be helpful with the following filters:

- Path: `databaseName.ldf` (prefer the full path if possible)
- Operation: `WriteFile`

Once your test is over, you can save it as CSV or XML for your evaluation. Unfortunately, the file size is in the detail column, which is a text column that includes other stuff that's not interesting for you. Since log files are likely appended, you need to calculate the total length yourself (offset + length).

[image: Screenshot of a hypothetical log file]

With some C# coding skills, you can use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). Benefit: you can log in the format that is best suitable for you. Disadvantage: potentially non-tested Spaghetti code that might have bugs.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileSizeChangeLogger
{
    static class Program
    {
        static long lastSize;
        static FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"D:\temp\myfilename.txt");

        static void Main()
        {
            lastSize = file.Length;

            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher {Path = file.DirectoryName};
            watcher.Changed += OnFileChange;

            while (true)
            {
                watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed);
            }
        }

        private static void OnFileChange(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.FullPath.Equals(file.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                file.Refresh();
                var newSize = file.Length;
                if (newSize != lastSize)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```